# Navigation action/destination error in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, navigation, android-navigation-graph

I'm trying to go from `StaveniFragment` to `StaveniZacatecnikFragment` after tapping on the `stavzac` (button id) ImageButton. Somehow, it keeps crashing after tapping the button for the second time.

The Logcat says this (at least I think this is the most interesting part):

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Navigation action/destination com.example.ludva2alpha:id/action_staveniFragment_to_staveniZacatecnikFragment cannot be found from the current destination Destination(com.example.ludva2alpha:id/staveniZacatecnikFragment) label=fragment_staveni_zacatecnik class=com.example.ludva2alpha.StaveniZacatecnikFragment
```

This is the **nav_graph.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/nav_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/staveniFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/staveniFragment"
        android:name="com.example.ludva2alpha.StaveniFragment"
        android:label="fragment_staveni"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_staveni" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_staveniFragment_to_staveniZacatecnikFragment"
            app:destination="@id/staveniZacatecnikFragment" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/staveniZacatecnikFragment"
        android:name="com.example.ludva2alpha.StaveniZacatecnikFragment"
        android:label="fragment_staveni_zacatecnik"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_staveni_zacatecnik" />
</navigation>
```

This is the **StaveniFragment.kt**:

```
package com.example.ludva2alpha

import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.ImageButton
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.navigation.fragment.findNavController
import com.example.ludva2alpha.databinding.FragmentStaveniBinding

class StaveniFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var binding: FragmentStaveniBinding

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        binding = FragmentStaveniBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        val view = binding.root

        // Find the stavzac ImageButton using data binding
        val stavzacButton: ImageButton = binding.stavzac

        // Set a click listener for the stavzac ImageButton
        stavzacButton.setOnClickListener {
            // Ensure that the fragment is hosted within a NavHostFragment
            val navController = findNavController()
            navController.navigate(R.id.action_staveniFragment_to_staveniZacatecnikFragment)
        }

        return view
    }
}
```

This is the **MainActivity.kt**:

```
package com.example.ludva2alpha

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.core.splashscreen.SplashScreen.Companion.installSplashScreen
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.navigation.NavController
import androidx.navigation.findNavController
import androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var bottomNavigationView: BottomNavigationView
    var currentPage = 0  // Initialize with the default fragment index (možná tam dej 0)
    private fun updateBottomNavigationBarIcons() {
        when (currentPage) {
            0 -> bottomNavigationView.selectedItemId = R.id.bottom_knihovna
            1 -> bottomNavigationView.selectedItemId = R.id.bottom_staveni
            2 -> bottomNavigationView.selectedItemId = R.id.bottom_domov
            3 -> bottomNavigationView.selectedItemId = R.id.bottom_programovani
            4 -> bottomNavigationView.selectedItemId = R.id.bottom_nastaveni
            // Add more cases if you have additional fragments
        }
    }

    private lateinit var navController: NavController
    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        navController = findNavController(R.id.navHostFragmentContainerView)
        return navController.navigateUp() || super.onSupportNavigateUp()
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        //Splash
        Thread.sleep(3000)
        installSplashScreen()
        //
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)


        //viewpager věci
        val viewPager: ViewPager2 = findViewById(R.id.view_pager)
        val fragmets: ArrayList<Fragment> = arrayListOf(
            KnihovnaFragment(),
            StaveniFragment(),
            DomovFragment(),
            ProgramovaniFragment(),
            NastaveniFragment()
        )
        //

        viewPager.registerOnPageChangeCallback(object : ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback() {
            override fun onPageSelected(position: Int) {
                currentPage = position
                // Update your Bottom Navigation Bar here based on currentPage
                updateBottomNavigationBarIcons()
            }
        })
        val adapter = ViewPagerAdapter(fragmets, this)
        viewPager.adapter = adapter


        bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation)

        bottomNavigationView.setOnItemSelectedListener { menuItem ->
            val currentItem = when (menuItem.itemId) {
                R.id.bottom_knihovna -> 0
                R.id.bottom_staveni -> 1
                R.id.bottom_domov -> 2
                R.id.bottom_programovani -> 3
                R.id.bottom_nastaveni -> 4
                else -> -1
            }

            if (currentItem >= 0) {
                viewPager.currentItem = currentItem
                true
            } else {
                false
            }
        }

        bottomNavigationView.selectedItemId = R.id.bottom_domov


    }

    /*private fun replaceFragment(fragment: Fragment){
        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit()
    } */
}
```

And this is the **StaveniZacatecnikFragment.kt**:

```
package com.example.ludva2alpha

import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment

class StaveniZacatecnikFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        // Find the ImageButton in the layout
       /* val imageButton = view.findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.stavzac)

        // Set an OnClickListener for the ImageButton to navigate to StaveniZacatecnikFragment
        imageButton.setOnClickListener {
            // Use findNavController().navigate to navigate to the desired fragment
            findNavController().navigate(StaveniFragmentDirections.actionStaveniFragmentToStaveniZacatecnikFragment())
        }*/
    }
}
```

I tried rearranging the order of the code parts in MainActivity, checked typos, asked several AIs several times, switched StaveniZacatecnikFragment for another fragment, did a clean rebuild and probably some other things.

Comment: It seems like you have a NavController that has fragments in it, but you also have a ViewPager2 that also has fragments in it that are completely separate from the NavController? You shouldn't be using a ViewPager2 if you are using a NavController. Is there a reason you aren't following the [connecting NavController to bottom nav guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/integrations/ui#bottom_navigation)?

Comment: Ummm... No. I made the bottom bar several months ago thanks to one tutorial. So I should probably remake that with nav_graph...